# Toolbar Item Click

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I am using toolbar in my app. Toolbar layout looks like this. I add `imageButton` inside toolbar as menu item. (Is that is a problem?) As I am new to Toolbar I don't know if this is the right way.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="top"
android:layout_height="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:gravity="right"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark">


<ImageButton
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_social_share"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:background="?selectableItemBackground"
    android:id="@+id/shareButton" />

<ImageButton
    android:src="@drawable/ic_tag"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:background="?selectableItemBackground"
    android:id="@+id/tagButton" />

<ImageButton
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_action_bookmark"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:background="?selectableItemBackground"
    android:id="@+id/bookmarkButton" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

And in `onCreate`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.newsdetail_activity);
    mActionBarToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mActionBarToolbar);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
 }
```

And `onOptionItemSelected`:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {


    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            break;
        case R.id.shareButton:

            Log.d(TAG, "SHARE BUTTON");

            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

The click on `shareButton` in toolbar is not firing. Can anyone tell the reason for this?

Comment: Show `onCreateOptionsMenu` method code

Comment: @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I ended up by using the following code

```
 ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.shareButton);

        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


            }
        });
```

I don't know if this the correct way.But it works

Comment: pay attention: that app will crash, if one of the menuItem is not visible from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
 case R.id.shareButton:    
            Log.d(TAG, "SHARE BUTTON");    
            break;
```

to

```
 case android.R.id.shareButton:    
        Log.d(TAG, "SHARE BUTTON");    
        break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_launcher);

        actionbar = getActionBar();
        actionbar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        actionbar.setCustomView(R.layout.action_bar_layout);

        btnClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClick);
        appIcon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.appIcon);
        appName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.appName);

        appName.setOnClickListener(this);
        appIcon.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnClick.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.appName:
            Toast.makeText(LauncherActivity.this, "You Clicked on App Name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        case R.id.appIcon:
            Toast.makeText(LauncherActivity.this, "You Clicked on App Icon", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        case R.id.btnClick:
            Toast.makeText(LauncherActivity.this, "You Clicked on Button", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        }
    }
```

See my git project [here](https://github.com/iamsarker/android-apps/tree/master/CustomActionBar)

Comment: I have to use toolbar in my project

Comment: This is Added in API level 21. What will be happen when API level is < 21? By the way you can check this link. http://blog.xamarin.com/android-tips-hello-toolbar-goodbye-action-bar/

Comment: or see this link... http://www.101apps.co.za/index.php/articles/using-toolbars-in-your-apps.html

Comment: I will check this link